# Difference equation when transfer function expressed as poles and zeros

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, z-transform

The transfer function $H(z)$:

$$
H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac {b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} + b_2 z^{-2}} {1 + a_1 z^{-1} + a_2 z^{-2}}
\tag{1}
$$

Has difference equation:

$$
y[n] = b_0 x[n] + b_1 x[n-1] + b_2 x[n-2] - a_1 y[n-1] - a_2 y[n-2]
\tag{2}
$$

How would you compute the difference equation when $H(z)$ is expressed as poles and zeros without expanding brackets:

$$
H(z) = g \frac {(z - d_0)(z - d_1)} {(z - c_0)(z - c_1)}
\tag{3}
$$

I'm happy to assume real poles and zeros for the sake of simplicity. I know that when performing a cascade on a computer that the output of the first section is fed to the second and second order sections are used. I'm interested in the maths though.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is get the difference equation for this expression direct without expansion:

$$
H(z) = g \prod_{k=1}^{K} \frac {b_{k0} + b_{k1} z^{-1} + b_{k2} z^{-2}} {1 + a_{k1} z^{-1} + a_{k2} z^{-2}}
\tag{4}
$$

Comment: What is $g$ in $H(z)$ ?

Comment: @Gilles: $g$ is the (real-valued) gain factor (which is not determined by the poles and zeros).

Comment: Why "without expanding brackets"? BTW, your notation is a bit strange, because $d_i$ are not the zeros, and $c_i$ are not the poles, but their inverses are.

Comment: @Matt L, thanks matt, given $d_i$ and $c_i$ are constants I supposed the maths would still hold either way, I've updated my question to be (hopefully) less strange :-)

Comment: The point that's still unclear to me is what keeps you from doing the obvious, i.e., expanding the brackets. If you want the difference equation then that's what you'll have to do.

Comment: @Matt L, fair point. I've updated the question with where I'm trying to end up. I thought asking a simpler question would give me enough clues to  get there.

Comment: @keith can you double-check you last equation ?

Comment: @Gilles, I've numbered the equations, do you mean (4)?

Comment: @Gilles, oh yes I see what you mean now, have updated. The general idea is that there are k sections each section has its own coefficients

Comment: So I guess this is a purely theoretical question, because in practice that problem doesn't occur, right? The answer is: if you want a difference equation as given in (2) you have to expand, i.e., compute the coefficients of the (total) numerator and denominator polynomials. Since this seems obvious, I'm afraid I might not have understood your question properly.

Comment: @Matt L, yes it's completely theoretical (a complex analysis question really). I thought that the inverse z transform can operate on a wider class of functions that rational polynomials though as you're implying it is limited to rational polynomials?

Comment: @keith: Your question really reduces to "how can I determine the coefficients of a polynomial that is the product of several other polynomials without actually performing the multiplication?" I don't think it really makes any sense.

Comment: @keith: The Z-transform *can* be used for a wider class of functions, but this is not the problem here. You do have ratios of polynomials, but they're just represented by their zeros instead of by their polynomial coefficients. However, the difference equation you're looking is by definition specified by the polynomial coefficients, so you must convert the zeros of the numerator and denominator polynomials to the respective coefficients. This has nothing to do with any limitations of the Z-transform.

Comment: @Matt L, in calculus you can differentiate a polynomial directly (using monic polynomial for simplicity) $1 + p_1x + p_2x^2$ or you can use the product rule to differentiate the same polynomial expressed as $(x - r_1)(x - r_2)$ directly. I think you would say they are the same and I would say they are different perhaps? I would say different because the final expression would have a different bracketing structure. I was hoping that the inverse z transform would have an analogy to this and it could somehow keep the structure in tact and there would be a pattern to this structure.

Comment: @Matt L, to summarise my comment above, I am particularly interested in the pattern of the final expression that is generated based on the initial expression's structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you would like to obtain a Linear Constant Coefficient Difference Equation (LCCDE) representation of a given system from its given System Transfer Function, $H(z)$, when it's expressed in a pole-zero product form such as:
$$
H(z) = g \frac {(z - d_0)(z - d_1)} {(z - c_0)(z - c_1)}
\tag{1}
$$

instead of a, more directly apparent, power series form such as:
$$
H(z) = \frac {b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} + b_2 z^{-2}} {1 + a_1 z^{-1} + a_2 z^{-2}}
\tag{2}
$$

As known, the latter form can be directly converted to its corresponding LCCDE representation from the coefficients ${b_k}$ and ${a_k}$ as follows:
$$y[n] + a_1 y[n-1] + a_2 y[n-2] = b_0 x[n] + b_1 x[n-1] + b_2 x[n-2]$$ 
Where the pattern of conversion speaks for itself, without a need of further description.

Now, we'd like to know whether one can obtain a similar conversion from the pole-zero form into the LCCDE **without expanding** the product?

Well yes and no! Depending on how you consider the process of computing the coefficents. If your intention is on the fact that you do not want to algebricaly perform the **paranthesis expansion** operation, but instead use a machanism that computes each coefficient **separately** by a set of arithmetic operations; then yes you can devise such a method to, for example, compute $a_3$ or $b_5$ without computing any other terms. And No, eventually you must always compute the coefficient $a_k$ that multiplies $z^{-k}$ so as to find the coefficient that multiplies $y[n-k]$, hence you need to always expand the brackets and compute multipliers of $z^{-k}$ in one or the other way.

Then I want to present here a simple method to find those coefficients :
given a polynomial in the product of zeros form: $$p(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$$ we can perform the following operation to get its coefficients in the expanded form $$p(x) = d_0 x^3 + d_1 x^2 + d_2 x + d_3$$

$$d[k] = (1 -a)\star(1 -b)\star(1-c)$$ where $k =0,1,2,3$ in this particular case.

As clearly seen this is a discrete **convolution** operation, where each multiplier bracket is turned into a respective convolution operand.  For which a simple MATLAB line to compute $d[k]$ would be:

```
 d = conv([1 -a],conv([1 -b],[1 -c]));
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` would be replaced by their numeric values or if you're competent in the symbolic math capability, you could instead obtain a pure symbolic result for the coeffients $d_k$, which would therefore give you a way to compute LCCDE coefficients from pole-zero products of $H(z)$ in a rather **roundabout** way.

Finally, the computations for a power of $z^{-1}$ products is basicly the same if you describe the product as $$P(z) = (1 - az^{-1})(1-bz^{-1})(1-cz^{-1})$$ and, 
$$P(z) = d_0 + d_1 z^{-1} + d_2 z^{-2} + d_3 z^{-3} $$

where again $$d[k] = (1 -a)\star(1 -b)\star(1-c)$$

Answer (score 2):

Considering a polynomial function written as:

\begin{align}
P(z) = (z-a_1)(z-a_2)\dots(z-a_{n-1})(z-a_n)
\end{align}

you can rewrite it as:

\begin{align}
P(z) = z^n - z^{n-1}\sum\limits_{i<n}a_{i}+z^{n-2}\sum\limits_{i\neq j}^{i,j\leq n}a_ia_j -z^{n-3}\sum\limits_{i\neq j \neq k}^{i,j,k\leq n}a_ia_ja_k\dots
\end{align}

For clarification, let's assume $n=3$. We obtain:

\begin{align}
P(z) = z^3-z^{2}(a_1 + a_2 + a_3)+z(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_1a_3)-a_1a_2a_3
\end{align}

For $n=4$:

\begin{align}
P(z) = &z^4-z^3(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)+z^2(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4)-\\&-z(a_1a_2a_3+a_1a_2a_4+a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3a_4)+a_1a_2a_3a_4
\end{align}

You can obtain coefficients for differential equation from the formula above.